# ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully, 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'

Tags: python, dockerfile, requirements.txt

I'm trying to build a Docker Image using this code:

```
FROM fedora:rawhide as build
    RUN yum install -y unzip && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chromedriver.zip" "https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/107.0.5304.62/chromedriver_linux64.zip" && \
    curl -Lo "/tmp/chrome-linux.zip" "https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/chromium-browser-snapshots/o/Linux_x64%2F1047731%2Fchrome-linux.zip?alt=media" && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver.zip -d /opt/ && \
    unzip /tmp/chrome-linux.zip -d /opt/

FROM fedora:rawhide
    RUN yum update -y && yum install atk cups-libs gtk3 libXcomposite alsa-lib \
    libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXi libXrandr libXScrnSaver \
    libXtst pango at-spi2-atk libXt xorg-x11-server-Xvfb \
    python3.9 python3-pip python3-wheel \
    xorg-x11-xauth dbus-glib dbus-glib-devel -y

COPY --from=build /opt/chrome-linux /opt/chrome
COPY --from=build /opt/chromedriver /opt/

ENV CHROME_BINARY_PATH=/opt/chrome/chrome
ENV CHROME_DRIVER_PATH=/opt/chromedriver

COPY *.txt  ./
COPY *.json ./
RUN yum update -y
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
COPY *.py ./

COPY entrypoint.sh .
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

This code has nothing different from other images I usually build, including the packages and versions which are those, in case it helps:

```
boto3==1.24.53
botocore==1.27.95
selenium==4.7.2
pandas==1.5.1
```

But I'm having the following full error message:

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.42kB                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/fedora:rawhide                                                              0.7s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                              0.0s
 => => transferring context: 196B                                                                                              0.0s
 => [build 1/2] FROM docker.io/library/fedora:rawhide@sha256:d05d3b242dc7113a120855c6f92ea6ec459345c4cb3ba490af93c523a3551d1f  0.0s
 => => resolve docker.io/library/fedora:rawhide@sha256:d05d3b242dc7113a120855c6f92ea6ec459345c4cb3ba490af93c523a3551d1f        0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  2/11] RUN yum update -y && yum install atk cups-libs gtk3 libXcomposite alsa-lib     libXcursor libXdama  0.0s
 => CACHED [build 2/2] RUN yum install -y unzip &&     curl -Lo "/tmp/chromedriver.zip" "https://chromedriver.storage.googlea  0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  3/11] COPY --from=build /opt/chrome-linux /opt/chrome                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  4/11] COPY --from=build /opt/chromedriver /opt/                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  5/11] COPY *.txt  ./                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  6/11] COPY *.json ./                                                                                      0.0s
 => CACHED [stage-1  7/11] RUN yum update -y                                                                                   0.0s
 => ERROR [stage-1  8/11] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt                                                                34.0s
------
 > [stage-1  8/11] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt:
#0 2.830 Collecting boto3==1.24.53 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
#0 3.118   Downloading boto3-1.24.53-py3-none-any.whl (132 kB)
#0 3.207      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 132.5/132.5 kB 1.6 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 5.128 Collecting botocore==1.27.95 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
#0 5.164   Downloading botocore-1.27.95-py3-none-any.whl (9.3 MB)
#0 6.171      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 9.3/9.3 MB 9.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 6.430 Collecting selenium==4.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
#0 6.470   Downloading selenium-4.7.2-py3-none-any.whl (6.3 MB)
#0 7.202      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 6.3/6.3 MB 8.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 7.409 Collecting urllib3==1.26.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
#0 7.440   Downloading urllib3-1.26.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (138 kB)
#0 7.477      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 138.1/138.1 kB 5.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 8.220 Collecting pandas==1.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
#0 8.259   Downloading pandas-1.5.1.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
#0 8.762      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.2/5.2 MB 10.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 10.18   Installing build dependencies: started
#0 33.48   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
#0 33.51   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 33.51   
#0 33.51   × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
#0 33.51   │ exit code: 1
#0 33.51   ╰─> [66 lines of output]
#0 33.51       Collecting setuptools>=51.0.0
#0 33.51         Downloading setuptools-68.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (804 kB)
#0 33.51            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 804.0/804.0 kB 2.0 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 33.51       Collecting wheel
#0 33.51         Downloading wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
#0 33.51            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 64.5/64.5 kB 4.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 33.51       Collecting Cython<3,>=0.29.32
#0 33.51         Downloading Cython-0.29.36-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
#0 33.51            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 988.3/988.3 kB 1.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 33.51       Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=0.10
#0 33.51         Downloading oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
#0 33.51       Collecting numpy (from oldest-supported-numpy>=0.10)
#0 33.51         Downloading numpy-1.25.1.tar.gz (10.4 MB)
#0 33.51            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.4/10.4 MB 1.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#0 33.51         Installing build dependencies: started
#0 33.51         Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#0 33.51         Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#0 33.51         Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'
#0 33.51         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 33.51       
#0 33.51         × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
#0 33.51         │ exit code: 1
#0 33.51         ╰─> [33 lines of output]
#0 33.51             Traceback (most recent call last):
#0 33.51               File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
#0 33.51                 main()
#0 33.51               File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 335, in main
#0 33.51                 json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
#0 33.51                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 33.51               File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 112, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
#0 33.51                 backend = _build_backend()
#0 33.51                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 33.51               File "/usr/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pyproject_hooks/_in_process/_in_process.py", line 77, in _build_backend
#0 33.51                 obj = import_module(mod_path)
#0 33.51                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 33.51               File "/usr/lib64/python3.12/importlib/__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
#0 33.51                 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
#0 33.51                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1293, in _gcd_import
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1266, in _find_and_load
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1216, in _find_and_load_unlocked
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 400, in _call_with_frames_removed
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1293, in _gcd_import
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1266, in _find_and_load
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1237, in _find_and_load_unlocked
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 841, in _load_unlocked
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 994, in exec_module
#0 33.51               File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 400, in _call_with_frames_removed
#0 33.51               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ogj3ubho/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
#0 33.51                 import setuptools.version
#0 33.51               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ogj3ubho/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/setuptools/version.py", line 1, in <module>
#0 33.51                 import pkg_resources
#0 33.51               File "/tmp/pip-build-env-ogj3ubho/overlay/lib/python3.12/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2172, in <module>
#0 33.51                 register_finder(pkgutil.ImpImporter, find_on_path)
#0 33.51                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#0 33.51             AttributeError: module 'pkgutil' has no attribute 'ImpImporter'. Did you mean: 'zipimporter'?
#0 33.51             [end of output]
#0 33.51       
#0 33.51         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 33.51       error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 33.51       
#0 33.51       × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
#0 33.51       │ exit code: 1
#0 33.51       ╰─> See above for output.
#0 33.51       
#0 33.51       note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 33.51       [end of output]
#0 33.51   
#0 33.51   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 33.52 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 33.52 
#0 33.52 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
#0 33.52 │ exit code: 1
#0 33.52 ╰─> See above for output.
#0 33.52 
#0 33.52 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
------
Dockerfile:33
--------------------
  31 |     COPY *.json ./
  32 |     RUN yum update -y
  33 | >>> RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
  34 |     COPY *.py ./
  35 |     
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I already tried changing the packages versions, adding dependencies manually as packages in the requirements.txt, and it didn't work.